# Does $1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots+ 2n$ mean the same thing as $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2n} i$?

Tags: summation, notation

Does $1 + 2 + 3 +\cdots + 2n$ mean the same thing as $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2n} i$?

Comment: I'm working on question #2 from ch 2 of Spivak's Calculus 3rd edition.

Comment: I originally read $1+2+3+...+2n$ as $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n 2i$, but this is obviously not correct. So, I just wanted to make sure that I understand the $1 + 2 + 3 +...+2n$ notation correctly.

Comment: Yes, it does${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: I would agree with your interpretation.

Comment: To quote my question on the StackExchange Math chat: "Huh, $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} (2n-1) = 1 + 3 + 5 + \ldots + (2n-1)$. On the other hand $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2n-1} i = 1 + 2 + 3 + \ldots + (2n-1)$?

Note: I'm working through an exercise in this text Calculus by Spivak.
I'm just very confused by this notation."

Comment: The point is, (2n -1) in the $\ldots$ notation isn't necessarily what goes directly on top of the Greek letter sigma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. $1+2+3+4+...+2n = \displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2n} i$

They can in fact be used interchangeably and denote the same sequence and number. One is just the compact form of writing the other.

Refer to [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation)

Comment: Surely they denote the same number, but the question was if they mean the same thing. $\sin\pi =\ln 1$, but the two sides have different meanings.

Comment: Define "meaning" in this context?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does. That's what a summation is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is, by the definition of summation.